# Como impedir um objeto de ser instanciado com determinada propriedade?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, instanciar-objeto

Eu desejo impedir um objeto de ser instanciado com um determinado valor (por exemplo, impedir que um objeto "bateria" possua um valor negativo ou acima de 100). Como eu posso impedir que ocorra a instância?
Exemplo de código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Fotocopiadora{
    private String modelo; // essa string não deve ser nula
    private int quantTinta;
    private String proprietario;


    public Fotocopiadora(String modelo, String proprietario){
        this.proprietario = proprietario;
        this.quantTinta = 100;

        this.modelo = ((modelo != null) && (!modelo.isEmpty())) ? modelo : "default"; // usado como substituição ao impedimento de instância
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimente assim. A exceção se for lançada irá impedir o objeto de ser instanciado.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Fotocopiadora{
    private String modelo; // essa string não deve ser nula
    private int quantTinta;
    private String proprietario;


    public Fotocopiadora(String modelo, String proprietario, int quantTinta){

        this.proprietario = proprietario;

        if (quantTinta < 0 || quantTinta > 100) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("QuantTinta inválido: " + quantTinta);
        }
        this.quantTinta = quantTinta;

        this.modelo = ((modelo != null) && (!modelo.isEmpty())) ? modelo : "default"; // usado como substituição ao impedimento de instância
    }

    // Este outro construtor aproveita o construtor já existente para
    // criar uma fotocopiadora com bateria 100% carregada. Isso se
    // chama sobrecarga de construtor.
    public Fotocopiadora(String modelo, String proprietario) {
        this(modelo, proprietario, 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cara, é por aí mesmo, obrigado